# Syntax error in autogenerated script by pgAdmin 3

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am starting to work on a project that involves a database in PostgreSQL.

I was able to create successfully a database.

After that I was asked to create a backup script using pgAdmin 3 in order transfer the database to my teammates.

The problem here is that they are not able to restore the database due to a syntax error, but I don't really know how to solve it since the script was autogenerated.

This is the beginning of the script:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.8
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.5

-- Started on 2017-08-23 15:54:22 CDT

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

DROP DATABASE "ConfigurationData";
--
-- TOC entry 2430 (class 1262 OID 16393)
-- Name: ConfigurationData; Type: DATABASE; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE DATABASE "ConfigurationData" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'C' LC_CTYPE = 'C';


ALTER DATABASE "ConfigurationData" OWNER TO postgres;

\connect "ConfigurationData"

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
```

The script fails in the \connect statement. I even tried to deleted the whole connect statement, but the tables got generated inside the default postgres database.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `\connect` is a `psql` command, you can't use that in pgAdmin. You need to use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Since I'm new at PostgreSQL, I didn't know anything about `psql`. However, the link you gave me helped me a lot. I was able to run my backup script correctly in a terminal window. Thanks. Just one question, is there a way to execute the psql from the pgAdmin app? After all, it is what that app is for, right? A UI to interact with PostgreSQL servers?